# Convert string to raw string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, string-literals, rawstring

```
char str[] = "C:\Windows\system32"

auto raw_string = convert_to_raw(str);

std::cout << raw_string;
```

Desired output:

```
C:\Windows\system32
```

Is it possible? I am not a big fan of cluttering my path strings with extra backslash. Nor do I like an explicit `R"()"` notation.

Any other work-around of reading a backslash in a string literally?

Comment: You might not like the syntax, but it's the syntax we've got. Welcome to C++.

Comment: If you're insane enough you can have PHP generate the code for you by using php as a preprocessor to c `<?php echo(addslashes('C:\Windows\system32'));?`> in the middle of a C file with .php extension... then dump the ouput and compile it as `.c` file.

Comment: How about forward slashes? They should work too.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, I was thinking about it. The problem is when working with registry, forward slashes are valid key-name characters. They rarely (if ever) appear in a key-name though

Comment: User defined string literal? That way you get to choose your own suffix, and you can do something like convert `/`  into a backslash.

Comment: @john Not gonna work, they will automatically interpret escape sequences.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But you could put some code behind them to convert forward to backward slashes

Comment: Out of curiosity ......    While I realise that neither `char raw_string[] = "C:\\Windows\\system32";` nor `char raw_string[] = R"(C:\Windows\system32)";` is your ideal, why do you consider that `char str[] = "C:\Windows\system32"; auto raw_string = convert_to_raw(str);` (if it was even possible, which it isn't) would be preferable?

Comment: @Peter Consider function call `get_location("C:\Windows\system32")`. In this case `convert_to_raw()` (or any equivalent operation) is performed inside a function and hidden away from the caller. Looks neat, much simpler

Comment: @user3600124   Yeah, well.   As long as you want to type string literals into source code, what you want aint possible.   The escaping (additional `\\`) or raw strings are THE ways to avoid that - and the standard doesn't provide a third way (to turn a string containing special characters back) because it is ambiguous in general.

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible, `\` has special meaning inside a non-raw string literal, and raw string literals exist precisely to give you a chance to avoid having to escape stuff. Give up, what you need is `R"(...)"`.

Indeed, when you write something like

```cpp
char const * str{"a\nb"};
```

[you can verify yourself that `strlen(str)` is 3, not 4](https://godbolt.org/z/zWv37s35s), which means that once you compile that line, in the binary/object file there's only one single character, the newline character, corresponding to `\n`; there's no `\` nor `n` anywere in it, so there's no way you can retrieve them.

---

As a personal taste, I find raw string literals great! You can even put real <kbd>Enter</kbd> in there. Often just for the price of 3 characters - `R`, `(`, and `)` - in addtion to those you would write anyway. Well, you would have to write more characters to escape anything needs escaping.

Look at

```cpp
std::string s{R"(Hello
world!
This
is
Me!)"};
```

That's 28 keystrokes from `R` to last `"` included, and you can see in a glimpse it's 6 lines.

The equivalent non-raw string

```cpp
std::string s{"Hello\nworld!\nThis\nis\nMe!"};
```

is 30 keystrokes from `R` to last `"` included, and you have to parse it carefully to count the lines.

A pretty short string, and you already see the advantage.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, as asked, no it is not possible.

As an example of the impossibility, assume we have a path specified as `"C:\a\b"`;

Now, `str` is actually represented in memory (in your program when running) using a statically allocated array of five characters with values `{'C', ':', '\007', '\010', '\000'}` where `'\xyz'` represents an OCTAL representation (so `'\010'` is a `char` equal to numerically to `8` in decimal).

The problem is that there is more than one way to produce that array of five characters using a string literal.

```
char str[] = "C:\a\b";
char str1[] = "C:\007\010";
char str2[] = "C:\a\010";
char str3[] = "C:\007\b";
char str4[] = "C:\x07\x08";    // \xmn uses hex coding
```

In the above, `str1`, `str2`, `str3,` and `str4` are all initialised using equivalent arrays of five `char`.

That means `convert_to_raw("C:\a\b")` could quite legitimately assume it is passed ANY of the strings above AND

```
std::cout << convert_to_raw("C:\a\b") << '\n';
```

could quite legitimately produce output of

```
C:\007\010
```

(or any one of a number of other strings).

The practical problem with this, if you are working with windows paths, is that `c:\a\b`, `C:\007\010`, `C:\a\010`, `C:\007\b`, and `C:\x07\x08` are all valid filenames under windows - that (unless they are hard links or junctions) name DIFFERENT files.

In the end, if you want to have string literals in your code representing filenames or paths, then use `\\` or a raw string literal when you need a single backslash.   Alternatively, write your paths as string literals in your code using all forward slashes (e.g. `"C:/a/b"`) since windows API functions accept those too.